# Fuzzy regression (using linear programming)

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, fuzzy

I want to replicate a fuzzy regression using a linear programming problem approach.

I have the following information: " A fuzzy regression analysis with only one independent variable X results in the following bivariate regression model:
$$ \hat{Y}=\tilde{A_o}+\tilde{A_1}X,$$

where $\tilde{A_o}$ is a is a fuzzy intercept, $\tilde{A_1}$is a fuzzy slope coefficient, the parameters are expressed as $\tilde{A_i}=(m_i,c_i)$ where $m_i$ is a centre  and $c_i$ is the fuzzy half-width."

To determine the fuzzy coefficients the following linear programming problem is used:

minimize $$ S= nc_0 + c_1\sum_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|$$

subject to $$c_0\geqslant0,\geqslant0,$$

$$\sum_{j=0}^{l}m_iX_{ij}+(1-h)\sum_{j=0}^{l}c_i|X_{ij}| \geqslant Y_i+(1-h), \mbox{for i=1 to n}$$

$$\sum_{j=0}^{l}m_iX_{ij}-(1-h)\sum_{j=0}^{l}c_i|X_{ij}| \geqslant Y_i-(1-h), \mbox{for i=1 to n}$$

where $h=0$

I have the following data :
$[X_i : Y_i]=[(2:14),(4:16),(6:14),(8:18),(10:18),(12:22),(14:18),
(16:22)]$

How to  solve the LP using R?

Answer (score -1):

the following book contain an example for solving this issue:

data driven modelling using MATLAB, for water resources and environmental engineers

look at chapter: Fuzzy Models

Comment: Welcome to this site! Could you provide a short overview of that particular chapter so that this reply remains self-contained?